weth address reverting overflow / underflow
My code is giving revert error overflow and underflow when I tried to interact with the weth token directly on blast chain, I’ve also imported safemath library which didn’t resolve the issue but if I changed the address to usbd or blast with same code, it executes with no error. It keeps happening when trying to interact with weth address..
NOTE: I’m not getting revert error if I supply other ERC20 and borrow weth using the same code. It’s also logging the weth balance with no error.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import {console, Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "./test/interfaces/IERC20.sol";
import "./test/interfaces/IWETH.sol";
import "./test/interfaces/IUni_Pair_V2.sol";

contract Pair_flashTest is Test {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    IUni_Pair_V2 private pair = IUni_Pair_V2(0x12c69BFA3fb3CbA75a1DEFA6e976B87E233fc7df);

    address private constant usbd = 0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000003;
    address private constant blast = 0xb1a5700fA2358173Fe465e6eA4Ff52E36e88E2ad;
    address private constant weth = 0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000004;

    function setUp() public {
        vm.createSelectFork("https://rpc.ankr.com/blast", 5561255);
        attacker = msg.sender;
        deal(address(weth), address(this), 10 ether);
        
    }

    function testloan() public {
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("weth before flashloan", IERC20(weth).balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
        
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(weth, 1999990 * 10**18);
        pair.swap(0, 3999999 * 10**18, address(this), data);

    }
    function uniswapV2Call(address sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, bytes calldata data) external {
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("weth during flash", IERC20(weth).balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
        
        // calculate fee for the loan
        uint256 fee = (uint256(3999999 * 10**18) * 3) / 997 + 1;
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("fee to pay during ", fee, 18);
        uint256 amountToRepay = 3999999 * 10**18 + fee;
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("flash loan amount to repay", amountToRepay, 18);

        // Ensure we have enough balance to repay the loan
        require(IERC20(weth).balanceOf(address(this)) >= amountToRepay, "Insufficient balance to repay the loan");
        // Repay the loan
        IERC20(weth).transfer(address(pair), amountToRepay);
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}


Try-
 vm.deal(address(this), 10.1 ether);
 vm.prank(address(this))
 IWETH(0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000004).deposit{value: 10 ether}();

replacing
deal(address(weth), address(this), 10 ether);


wow. it solved it perfectly. seems the issue is related to wrapped ETH and wrapped BNB interaction with contract has some additional steps different from ERC20 implementations.. thank you for this

Glad it solved you issue :) . Please mark the answer as correct .
